# WARN EclipseJavaCompiler Using unsupported java version '11', assuming latest supported version '9' when running AEM 6.5 on Java 11

Tags: java, aem, java-11

When running AEM 6.5.3 on Java 11 I noticed suspicious WARN messages appearing in error.log from time to time:

```
08.01.2020 16:33:06.236 WARN [10.0.2.2 [1578497585926] GET /editor.html/content/* HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.commons.compiler.impl.EclipseJavaCompiler Using unsupported java version '11', assuming latest supported version '9'
```

It looked like a warning during JSP compilation but [forcing JSP recompilation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/How-to-force-a-recompilation-of-all-Sling-scripts-jsps-java-sightly-on-AEM-6-4.html) is not triggering this WARN. I wonder if this is a known issue and if it can cause any troubles when executing JSPs?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this issue is already fixed in [SLING-8322](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-commons-compiler/commit/ae8672e9c47b5e2153a22e904c3ef420322949ac) but is not released yet. I assume that, at the moment of writing, it is impossible to use Java 10+ code in any AEM JSP files. Beyond that, all works fine - experience from two different projects.

Comment: See the article about running AEM 6.5 on Java 11 for more details: https://tech.cognifide.com/blog/2020/aem-on-java-11-with-gradle/